# Sculpting with Bezier/NURBS object

Tags: sculpting, bezier-curves

Imagine the following to make a landscape. I have created a plane. Then I add, to the plane, bezier curves, either closed or open. Then I want to "lift" the bezier curves to raise part of the plane to form plateau's or ridge's with nice smooth slopes following the Bezier curves. The important part here is, by using Bezier curves and the known form of slope, I will be able calculate the slope grade anywhere on the slopes. I need to do this calculation when the plane/landscape is used in games.
So, how can I sculpt with Bezier curves/forms?

Comment: I suggest looking into [NURBS surfaces](https://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/surfaces/introduction.html).